# Why does my Ajax success function never trigger?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My `$.ajax` success function never triggers. I just want to execute a PHP file without passing and getting ANY values. I am using another way of reading values, but it can't be run since the function needs to be put in the `$.ajax` success function, which does not work.

#### Code:

```
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        var interval;

        function ajaxify()
        {
            $.ajax
            (
                {
                    url:"http://localhost/twitter/redirectFollow.php",
                    success:function()
                    {
                        $("#resultPara").prepend("test123"); // This does not trigger
                    }
                }
            );  //  End $.ajax
        }   //  End ajaxify

        $("#buttonClick").click
        (
            function()
            {
                ajaxify();
            }
        );  //  End buttonClick
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried just doing this instead of $.ajax: `$.get("http://localhost/twitter/redirectFollow.php", function() {$("#resultPara").prepend("test123")});` Same problem?

Comment: I would start with adding an error handler: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Firebug or equivalent tool to ensure the request is being made successfully and that you are receiving a response.

My guess would be that since you are specifying an absolute url, the request is being seen as a cross-domain request. If the script you are requesting resides on the same domain the javascript is on, shorten the url to `/twitter/redirectFollow.php`, otherwise you will have to use a data-type of JSONP. [See docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Solved it.. Problem was in my php script where i was performing semi infinite loop, which would never trigger any responce. The $.get method is way better than the stuff that i was trying, so very big thank to you guys!

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a problem in your ajax request, your request is not successful, hence no call to success.

Your code works just fine in the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sgbup/ (with the ajax echo service)

check the calls with firebug or with chrome's javascript console.

Comment: Infinite php loop.. thanks for responding! I was busting my head all day trying to find what's wrong..